# Indicator function of triangle function - Bochner's theorem

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, spectral-theory, fourier-transform

Let $\theta(t) = (1-|t|)^+$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. In order to show that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \theta(t) e^{-i \xi t}\ dt = \bigg(\frac{sin\big(\frac{\xi}{2}\big)}{\frac{\xi}{2}}\bigg)^2, \qquad (*)
\end{align}
I want to compute the Fourier transform of $\phi(t) = \mathbb{1}_{\{-1/2 \leq t \leq 1/2\}}$ and relate this to $\theta$.

It could be shown that the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of $\phi$ equals
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\xi) = \frac{\sin(\pi \xi)}{\pi \xi}. \qquad (**)
\end{align} 
Making the substitution $u = \frac{1}{2}t$ in $(*)$ gives
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \theta(t) e^{-i \xi t}\ dt = 2 \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} (1-|2u|)^+ e^{-2i \xi u}\ du \qquad (***)
\end{align}
and could be worked out. However, I do not see how $(**)$ could be related to $(***)$. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $\theta$ as $1_I\ast1_I$ for an interval $I$. Say $I=[-a,a]$. Then you have to compute
$$
\int_{-a}^a1_{[-a,a]}(x-t)dt.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The statement follows indeed from there. However I am quite unfamiliar with these calculations. Could you maybe elaborate this further?

Comment: $$\mathbb{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]} * \mathbb{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]} (x) = \int_{\max(-1/2, x-1/2)}^{\min(1/2, x+1/2)} dt$$
$$ = \begin{cases} 0 \qquad \text{if $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$} \\ 1-x \qquad \text{if $0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2}$} \\ 1+x \qquad \text{if $\frac{-1}{2} < x <0$} \\ 0 \qquad \text{if $x \leq \frac{-1}{2}$}\end{cases}$$ could be plugged in $(***)$. To make ends meet, how do we have to use the Fourier transform of $\phi$?

Comment: @iJup Careful with Tex! All the text boxes in the cases -environment missed the closing dollar-sign around the formula. Also, it is **NEVER** a good idea to use more than 80 characters of TeX without a break in the comments. The comments are parsed differently, and extra spaces will be added by the sparser - with random side effects.

Comment: Okido, I will do! @Julián, I solved my question. Thanks! I used that $\int_\mathbb{R} (\phi * \phi)(t) e^{-i \xi t}\ dt = (\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(t)e^{-i \xi t}\ dt)^2$.